# Verify text on page without locator

Tags: playwright, playwright-python, playwright-test, playwright-java

[image]I am using playwright, working with an ERP (IFS) system and I can't figure out the locator for my text on page to be verified. How can we verify the text on a page without locator?

I tried the following

```
expect(this.page.getByText('Success!').isVisible());
```

To my surprise when I tried following it still passes when "Go home" does not exists on the page, so clearly something is wrong there

```
expect(this.page.getByText('Go home!').isVisible);
```

I tried with followin

```
expect(page.locator(('#Form-WorkOrderContactList-fndRow-1-Cf_Contact_Type'))).toBe("Success");
```

it gives error as follow

```
Expected: "Success" 
Received: {"_frame": {"_guid": "frame@b4a0f19f2bc5a31359f192d5bab34ac7", "_type": "Frame"}, "_selector": "internal:attr=[title=\"Case Handler\"i] >> div >> nth=0"}
```

I have added a picture, its an IFS System, I tried so many things in last two days but no luck, any help will be appreciated. I am using typescript

Comment: Look at your parenthesis, you are not calling the method `isVisible()`. Try this: `expect(this.page.getByText('Success!')).isVisible()`

Comment: @candre Its the same after paranthesis  Even if the text does not exists on the page it passes. I tired with following locator

Comment: @candre I tried with following 
expect(page.locator(('#Form-WorkOrderContactList-fndRow-1-Cf_Contact_Type'))).toBe("Success");
it gives error as follow
Expected: "Success"
    Received: {"_frame": {"_guid": "frame@b4a0f19f2bc5a31359f192d5bab34ac7", "_type": "Frame"}, "_selector": "internal:attr=[title=\"Case Handler\"i] >> div >> nth=0"}

Comment: Please [edit] the post when you wish to add more code. It's hard to read otherwise. Thanks. That said, without the page and a [mcve], it'll still be very difficult to help. Websites have arbitrary behavior that's difficult to guess blindly. Trying many things is good, but if you don't show each unsuccessful attempt in a complete, runnable manner, it doesn't do prospective answerers much good.

Comment: Is there any way of knowing what is the page? If not, as @ggorlen says, we need more code to know where the problem could be. Or a screenshot of the page.

Comment: @ggorlen I have added a picture now and Formatted the error too

Comment: Thanks, but I can't scrape a picture. There's still not enough to work off of. I'd have to see the website or a simple reproduction of it that has the same behavior, if you can't share the actual site.